# Selecting macports python as default in non-admin account

Tags: python, macports

I have two accounts on my system, an admin account and a user account.

I use the admin account to install macport and have set the default python using

```
sudo port select --set python python27
```

On the user account I can run all the python I need using

```
/opt/local/bin/python
```

but how do I select that to be default?

```
port select --list python
```

reports

```
python27 (active)
```

but

which python returns

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Does this belong here, or on SuperUser?

Comment: Just set your `PATH` appropriately (and `PYTHONPATH`, for that matter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a shell question. `which python` returns the first python on your PATH environment variable. The PATH variable is a list of paths that the shell searches for executables. This is usually set in .profile, .bash_profile or .bashrc. If you reorder your paths, such that `/opt/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` then `/opt/local/bin/python` will be your default.
This will also be return by `#!/usr/bin/env python`, which is the normal shebang put at the top of python scripts.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the stupid question. Fixing my path fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alias python=/opt/local/bin/python` in your .bashrc, or the equivalent rc file for your shell.

Comment: Also I don't believe the alias would be picked up by the normal shebang for python scripts `#!/usr/bin/env python`.